# android viewpager with scrollbar

Tags: android

Is there anyway to associate a scroll bar with view pager,normal view pager indicator doesn't meet my requirement. Am looking for a way to add scroll bar just below the view pager. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The circle indicator and a scroll bar performs really similar, if you can change the circles with a line you are done.

Comment: Check out this library: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

There are several types if indicators including scroll indicator.